# How to stop Facebook like/share buttons from jumping on page load?

Tags: css, facebook

I added Facebook's Like & Share buttons on my website, but on about 50% of page loads the iframe loads off to the right and then jumps back left where it should be.

Here's a test URL:

http://www.pricewombat.com/p/105674/B00DVFLJDS/ASUS-New-Nexus-7-FHD-Tablet-Black

Since it doesn't happen every time, here's a video showing the behavior:

http://www.screencast.com/t/CKrwd8cljxm

I've used the buttons on other parts of my website without this problem, so I'm thinking the issue may have something to do with the positioning of the parent elements.

How can this be fixed?

Note: I can't just use `overflow: hidden;` on the parent element of the Facebook iframe, because when the Like or Share buttons are clicked, they open up a comment window that needs to be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `width: 124px;` to `.fb_iframe_widget span`.

```
.fb_iframe_widget span {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 124px;
}
```

Comment: It's an iframe, so I don't think I can use css to modify it's contents.

Comment: As far as I can see, it is the `span` surrounding the `iframe` so you can still modify its css. [Image](http://i.imgur.com/b3C9Nj3.png)

Comment: You're right, I thought you meant spans inside the iframe. I tried adding the CSS (you can see it's added now), but unfortunately it didn't seem to fix the problem. According to Chrome Dev Tools, the css gets overwritten by Facebook's css.

Comment: Yes it supposed to get overwritten by Facebook's CSS and that is why it jumps back once those CSS rules get applied. So you apply the CSS immediately preventing the jumping. I tried refreshing the page a couple of times and it doesn't seem to jump anymore?

Comment: It's inconsistent. I just had to refresh it 8 times for it to jump, but then I did it again and it only took 3 times.. I think the parent container having `text-align: right;` was causing the issue for some reason. I instead changed it to `left` and the issue has gone away. Thanks for your help.